# what does the 2nd return_type mean in 'int APIENTRY _tWinMain'

Tags: c++, c, win32gui

I am a beginner in C++ and am learning the WIN32 Gui.

The only function declaration/definition I have ever seen is of the format:

```
return_type function_name(parameters...)
```

In `int APIENTRY _tWinMain`, `int` is the return type. **What does 
`APIENTRY` mean?**

Comment: I needed to know what does the 2nd return_type mean. Not what it actually do. Please read the content before you flag it duplicate.

Comment: I have reformatted your post to make it clearer, amal. I hope it isn't too drastic. If it is, you may rollback.

Comment: @amaljith The answer to the question I think you're trying to ask is "it's _not_ a second return type; it's not part of the return type at all.  It is a modifier applied to the function itself.  It's in the same category of modifiers as `static` on a function definition." (I anticipate getting yelled at by pedants for that last sentence, but I do not have room in this comment box to satisfy them.)

Answer (score 3):

`APIENTRY` is an alias for `WINAPI`.

This macro evaluates to [`__stdcall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx), which is a Microsoft specific calling convention that:

> is used to call Win32 API functions. The callee cleans the stack, so the compiler makes vararg functions __cdecl. Functions that use this calling convention require a function prototype.

It is basically a keyword that Microsoft added so you could get the behavior listed above. There are many similar keywords that Microsoft has added as well, such as`__cdecl`, `__circall`, and `__fastcall`.

The syntax for this is listed in the documentation:

```
return-type __stdcall function-name[(argument-list)]
```